# Execution failed for task ':compileIntegrationTestGroovy'

Tags: testing, grails, functional-testing

I created an application with

```
grails create-app TestApp
```

I've created test with

```
grails create-functional-test Test
```

When I tried to start test with

```
grails test-app
```

It gave me an error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileIntegrationTestGroovy'.
```

The question is how to run tests and solve this problem?
Maybe I've missed some dependencies?

Output is:
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileIntegrationTestGroovy'.

> org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.addMethodGenerics(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/MethodNode;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map;

UPD:

```
grails test-app --stacktrace
```

returns a long stacktrace with

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
```

org.codehaus.groovy.ast.tools.GenericsUtils.addMethodGenerics(Lorg/codehaus/groovy/ast/MethodNode;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljava/util/Map;

UPD

The test is

```
package myapp

import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*

import geb.spock.*

/**
  * See http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/ for more instructions
 */
@Integration
@Rollback
class TestSpec extends GebSpec {

  def setup() {
  }

  def cleanup() {
  }

  void "test something"() {
      when:"The home page is visited"
          go '/'

      then:"The title is correct"
            title == "Welcome to Grails"
  }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough of the error to know what is going wrong but the answer to "Maybe I've missed some dependencies?" is no.  If you follow the 3 steps you described above, that normally works.

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, 3.3.0

Comment: @JeffScottBrown, I've updated question with more information about output

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Grails 3.3.0, there was a problem in the generated test templates so in your integration test you will want to replace this...

```
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
```

With this...

```
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
```

Comment: generated imports are OK, so it stil returns the same error.

Comment: "generated imports are OK" - That surprises me.  3.3.0 has a bug that would be inconsistent with that.  After fixing the import then the test should run.  I pasted the code directly from your code above into a newly created 3.3.0 project and it works as expected.  Something is wonky in your env because the code you show above should not be what `create-functional-test` generates if you are using 3.3.0.

Comment: The error you show now is a different error than would have been demonstrated using the 3 steps you started the question with.  What JDK are you using?

Comment: JVM Version: 1.8.0_73
Groovy Version: 2.4.11

Comment: What you are reporting doesn't make sense to me.  This is what I would expect to see: http://jeffscreencasts.s3.amazonaws.com/testing_problem.mp4

Comment: The fact that your Grails 3.3.0 generated `import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration` tells me something is wrong in your environment.  That should not have happened.

Comment: The fact that your project is using Groovy 2.4.11 is another weird detail.  Grails 3.3.0 ships with a dependency on Groovy 2.4.7.

Comment: I suggest that you try using `./grailsw test-app` and separately try `./gradlew iT`.  (if you are using Windows, do the same thing but omit the `./` in front of the wrapper names)

Comment: "both methods returns same errors" - I am sorry that I can't help.  The fact that your `create-functional-test` generates something different than everyone else's tells me that something is wangled in your environment.  Good luck.

Comment: if i try to create a new app than it return the error like you send in video, which is solvable.
Maybe its better to transfer my old project's file to the new one =\

Comment: Thank you, anyway)